# Forms 11g freezes while executing web.javascript_eval_expr() window.open

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to load a webpage by using this code inside a WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger

```
BEGIN

web.javascript_eval_expr ('window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank","menubar=0,location=0,toolbar=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=500,height=600");');

END;
```

The new window opens  correctly, but when closing it and continue to use the form it won't let you perform any action.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known defect and has been fixed by oracle ( bug 14634027 ).

Comment: While this might be helpful the original poster, it would be better to add this as a comment to the question (which you can do at 10 reputation).